# Facebook -- can't find how to stop email notifications

Tags: facebook, email, notifications

I'm receiving a bunch of group activity notifications from Facebook in a corporate account, and when I click at the "Edit mail settings" link at the bottom, I get this screen:

[image: Facebook account options]

As you can see, there's not a "*Notifications*" menu or anything similar as when I log in with my personal account, where there's a "*Group activity*" setting.

Please help me stop receiving these annoying e-mails.

Edit:

As suggested by @Miranda, I tried to go to the group page to disable notifications, but whenever I click on the "View post on Facebook" link I get redirected to this landing page:

[image: Facebook advertising page]

Well, I'm stuck, and still receiving a bunch of daily free SPAM.

Comment: can you navigate to the page directly? https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=notifications

Comment: No, @phantom42, that's the same as going to https://www.facebook.com/settings =/

Answer (score 1):

You might go to the grup page and turn off notifications from there.

[image: Example]